# foreign key references either Compte(id) or sousCompte(id) or Rubrique(id) etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry in advance, I am having a really hard time putting my question into real words. I think I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how foreign keys work. 
here is my tables :

- ->compte : idC , desci , debit , credit
- ->sousCompte :idSc , idC , descri , debit,credit --idc is a foreign key from table compte
- ->rubrique : idR, idSc , descri , debit , credit -- idSc is a  foreign key from table sousCompte .
- -> Mouvement :id , idCompte , debit credit  -- **idcompte is a foreign key references either Compte or sousCompte or Rubrique**

so how can i point idCompte as foreign key references from  several tables just like the example abouve .

Comment: So you're asking if the foreigen key column (Mouvement.idCompte) of your table can point to an ID column in two different tables?

Comment: yep !  i  wonder, if is it possible to have a foreign key  references from many id  tables . this is the best approach , but i don't know how to rewrite it in sql .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inner join your Movement against all tables you want to compare with and leave a marker of 1 for existence. In an outer query sum up all the markers grouped by MouvementID.

```
SELECT
    MouvementId=Mouvement.id,
    ReferencesCompte=MAX(compteFlag),
    ReferencesSousCompte=MAX(sousCompteFlag),
    RefrencesRubrique=MAX(rubriqueFlag)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Mouvement.id,
        compteFlag=CASE WHEN NOT C.idC IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        sousCompteFlag=CASE WHEN NOT SC.idSC IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        rubriqueFlag=CASE WHEN NOT R.idR IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    FROM
        Mouvement M
        LEFT OUTER JOIN compte C ON C.idC=M.idCompte
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sousCompte SC ON SC.idC=M.idCompte
        LEFT OUTER JOIN rubrique R ON R.idR=M.idCompte
)AS DATA
GROUP BY
    Mouvement.id
```